# How to get a list of record ignored by Trigger.add Error method

Tags: apex, trigger

Wondering If we can get a list of records got ignored by Trigger add error method. We have a trigger which blocks the duplicates records coming into salesforce from Web to Case HTML Form using Trigger.add method. I was wondering if we can get a list how many cases got ignored as per logic compared to the cases already there in salesforce.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the *caller* can get this information by doing

```
Database.SaveResult[] srs = Database.insert(listOfCases, false);
```

But that doesn't apply in this situation, since the insert operation is not under your control. Your trigger would need to persist details about the cases that have been rejected to a Custom Setting (if you're just storing a count) or a Custom Object (to log details about the rejected Cases)  to record those errors.

Once errors have been returned to the caller, those objects are gone, since they're not inserted or persisted in the database. Your only opportunity to record them is in the trigger itself.

Comment: Thanks, David. I had the same thought but just wanted to confirm.